# Android app opens multiple times using Firebase authentication

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

So I have been scratching my head for hours now, I am using Firebase authentication in my android app and for some reason it keeps popping up randomly it opens multiple times basically, after researching I found that it is probably the method AuthStateListener.

I have tried adding a flag like people who were having the same problem but to no avail, where should I start my activity if the Firebase user or authentication does not equal to null without the app spontaneously opening up by itself. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is my code

```
mAuthListner = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
  @Override
  public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
    if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
      firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
      //Log.i("User1",firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().toString());
      FirebaseUser firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
      if (!isMyServiceRunning(MyService.class))
        startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class));

      //prefManager = new PrefManager(getApplicationContext());
      if (MyPreferences.isFirst(getApplicationContext()) || !databaseOperations.checkUser(databaseOperations)) {
        launchHomeScreen();
      } else { 
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainDrawer.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK));
        finish();
      }
    }
  }
}
};
```

Comment: Have you tried working through this guide before? https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/start/

Comment: Yes I have read through it several times, my question is where do I  start my activity so that auth state listener does not re run my activity even when the user did not open the app, I can post more of my code if that will help